# How do I use clearInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an interactive car game/HTML web-based thing on repl.it. I'm trying to do the windshield wipers with a setInterval/clearInterval system but the clearInterval() function is not working for me. It wouldn't clear the interval.

```js
var interval = '';

function startInterval() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'type code';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'other code';
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}

function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: The code works fine, but remember that you are using `setTimout`, so even if you call `stopInterval()`, the interval on hold, will fire ... you could do is, start the interval in `0` and  upon `clearInterval()` set the interval to `0` again ... inside the setTimeout, only run the code if `interval > 0` ... does it makes sense? [like this](https://jsbin.com/museduv/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, Welcome to StackOverflow

Your code works fine, but remember that you are using `setTimout`, so even if you call `stopInterval()`, the code inside the timeout will fire once more

to prevent it, you could do this

- start the interval with `0`
- when `clearInterval()` set the interval to `0` once again
- now, inside the `setTimeout` function, only run the code if `interval > 0`

does it makes sense?

here's a simple example in [JsBIN](https://jsbin.com/museduv/edit?html,js,output) and well with StackOverflow Code:

```js
var pre = document.querySelector("pre")
var interval = 0;

function startInterval() {
  pre.innerHTML += 'START called\n';
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    pre.innerHTML += 'type code\n';

    setTimeout(function() {
      if (interval > 0 ) {
        // only if the interval is not cleared
        pre.innerHTML += 'other code\n';
      }
    }, 1000);
    
  }, 2000);
}

function stopInterval() {
  pre.innerHTML += 'STOP called\n';
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = 0;
}

document
  .querySelector("#btnStart")
  .addEventListener("click", startInterval);
document
  .querySelector("#btnStop")
  .addEventListener("click", stopInterval);
```

```html
<button id="btnStart">START</button> <button id="btnStop">STOP</button>
<hr/>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to define `interval` variable outside of function:

```
let interval;
function startInterval() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'type code';
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'other code';
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}

function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
``
```

Comment: That is what I did, otherwise I can't use it in a different function or if then else statement if I needed to. Sorry I didn't make sure you saw that. I will edit it.