# Nested `setTimeout`s in `for` loop

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have multiple bulbs in one array. I'm trying to turn on and off the bulbs one by one. Each bulb should be turned ON for 1 second (one by one) and then all bulbs should be OFF for 2 seconds.

But in the below code, the output is not in the expected order. Seems like the inner `setTimeout()` does not follow the delay time of the outer one.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i + " is on");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i + " is off");
    }, i * 1000);
  }, i * 3000);
}
```

I do not have to use `setTimeout()` here (if there's a better alternative).

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: can't you use `setInterval`? check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61163773/28004

Comment: What is the expected order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested timeout (`off`) will be set only when its "parent" timeout (`on`) fires.

That way, your `off`-timeouts' times are *added* to `on`-timeouts times (`i * 3000 + i * 1000`):

```
0*3000 + 0*1000 =     0
1*3000 + 1*1000 =  4000
2*3000 + 2*1000 =  8000
3*3000 + 3*1000 = 12000
4*3000 + 4*1000 = 16000
5*3000 + 5*1000 = 20000
```

If you compare these values to the `on`-timeouts, you get:

```
ON  0     0
OFF 0     0
ON  1  3000
OFF 1  4000
ON  2  6000
OFF 2  8000
ON  3  9000
OFF 3 12000
ON  4 12000
ON  5 15000
OFF 4 16000
OFF 5 20000
```

Therefore, there's no need for `i *` in case of `off`-timeouts.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i + " is on");
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i + " is off");
    }, 1000);
  }, i * 3000);
}
```

Also, it is better to avoid nested timeouts if possible, because they add up their delays. Instead, create them with their time added.

Like this:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i + " is on");
  }, i * 3000);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i + " is off");
  }, i * 3000 + 1000);
}
```

Comment: @JingFan I've added a Fiddle with START and STOP if you need https://jsfiddle.net/balexandre/5oq0ctLf/